# Random string on button press

Tags: android, arrays, string, random

I am trying to get a random string from an array when I press a button.

So far it works with getting a random string when the application starts up, but I cannot get it to work on press of a button after startup.

EDIT:
It now crashes on start up??

My new code:

```
private String[] myString;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joke);
  Resources res = getResources();

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.Jokes); 

    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];    
    tv.setText(q);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) {

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.Jokes); 

    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];    
    tv.setText(q);
  }
});

}
}
```

Logcat says:

```
03-31 22:47:35.777: W/dalvikvm(1152): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-31 22:47:35.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jc.dkjokes/com.jc.dkjokes.DanskeJokesMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1612)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.jc.dkjokes.DanskeJokesMain.<init>(DanskeJokesMain.java:17)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
03-31 22:47:35.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     ... 11 more
03-31 22:47:35.963: I/dalvikvm(1152): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-31 22:47:36.148: I/dalvikvm(1152): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

- SnoX

Comment: where is your button's on click event or code ?

Comment: Is the button responsive at all? And yes, you need to post the relevant code  of course...

Comment: Where is your onClick event.  Search for onClick to find thousands of examples.  I would also move the code to get a random string into a function.  That way if it works in onCreate, it will work anywhere.  If you have any further trouble post your code and someone will jump in.

Comment: @Snox declare this line  Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
in onCreate() . .

Comment: @Snox i update your question . Please check that code and run it . .

Comment: Okay so now it shows a random string on press. But not onCreate? I want it to show a string when the app start also :P

Comment: @SnoX Please check your question again my friend

Comment: Thanks, its all working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you need to declare one button in your main.xml file then you have to initialize that in your activity. Then after you have to set on click event listener on that button.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    />
```

**Code**

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joke);
Button btn = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.buttonClick);
    btn.setonclickListener(new onClickListner(){
          public void onclick()
          {
               myString =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Jokes); 
               String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
               tv.setText(q);
          }
    });
```

Comment: where ? can you please describe ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to define onClickListener() for generating string on button click, Something like this,

```
    Button btn = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.yourbuttonid);
    btn.setonclickListener(new onClickListner(){
          public void onclick()
          {
               //write your oncreate code here again
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined an `onClickListener` for your `Button`. Do so as follows:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.joke);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String[] myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Jokes); 
        tv.setText(myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)]);
    }
});
```